# Compatible boolean data type of various relational databases

Tags: sql, mysql, database, sqlite, postgresql

I am trying to create a select statement that is compatible with all major relational databases (MySQL, PostgreSQL, Derby, SQLite, ...).

Here the simple select statement: `SELECT * FROM taggings WHERE public IS TRUE`

The problem is that SQLite for example does not support the boolean data type, so I rewrote my statement to: `SELECT * FROM taggings WHERE public = 1`

As far as I know it is valid for SQLite (wich uses some kind of byte for the public field) and also MySQL (which interprets the 1 as true, cause it uses the boolean type for the public field).

How about PostgreSQL when also uses a boolean public field? From the manual it looks like that I have to write `SELECT * FROM taggings WHERE public = '1'`. Or is that equivalent in that case to the above statement? (I don't have a chance to setup a PostgreSQL database here.)

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM taggings WHERE public
```

Comment: And this also works for those databases that doesn't have the boolean type but store a 0 for false?

Comment: At least all that I know of. Among those then ones you mentioned.